# How do I clean xDB in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, analytics, sitecore8, sitecore-xdb

Have recently tried working with xDB in Sitecore 8 and now looking for the way of cleaning out current stats from xDB without re-installing Sitecore. I deleted data files for Mongo (as was suggested) but still see figures in Analytics in Sitecore; also did iisreset but also did not help. What am I doing wrong? (I am new to Sitecore so might be missing something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to clean-up only MongoDB files, without Reporting database?

If yes, I think that is a point of your confusion. The way it works in xDB is that all tracking analytics data is written into Mongo and then by SessionEnd processed and saved into **Reporting** database, that is **SQL** database, same way as it was before previously in DMS. In that case you need to clean that database as well.

If you have access to SQL, you may use `__DeleteAllReportingData` stored procedure as the quickest:

[image]

More correct approach that goes well for instances where there is no direct access to DB is using admin tool for that located at **/sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx**. Also there was a module [Analytics Database Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx) previously, however I do not know its current state.

Reference: [Walkthrough: Rebuilding the reporting database](https://doc.sitecore.net/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/xDB%20configuration/Walkthrough%20Rebuilding%20the%20reporting%20database) *(from official documentation)*

Comment: Might want to obscure the database name in the right hand side - can still see the customer name.

Comment: No worries, that does not make any isues.

Comment: It does create an issue for me; this screenshot is mine, from this page:  http://andrewwburns.com/2015/04/28/clearing-sitecore-analytics-data/  I have replaced this with an obscured one; please use that in the future.